# Multithreading vs Singlethreading process runtimes

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I'm currently working on a multithreading mergesort program.
I'm comparing the different run times between multithread vs single thread.
Ive came up with an average of .022279s (multi) vs .00249s (single)

My question is why is the single thread application faster than my multithread?

Isn't multithread supposed to be more efficient compared to single thread?

Multi Thread code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void *run(void *parameters); /* threads call this function */
int alength, flength;
int *array_whole;

FILE *input_file;
int *read_file(char *file_name) {
    input_file = fopen("soulfoodinput.txt", "rt"); // open file
    int arraysize = flength;
    char line[80];
    int integer;
    int index = 0;
    int *input = malloc(arraysize * sizeof(int));


    while (fgets(line, 80, input_file) != NULL) 
{
        sscanf(line, "%d", &integer); // read the integer value
        input[index] = integer;
        //printf(line);
        ++index;
        ++alength;
    }
    fclose(input_file); // close the file    
    return input;
}


int read_length(char *file_name) {
    input_file = fopen(file_name, "rt"); // open file
    char line[80];
    int file_length = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 80, input_file) != NULL) {
        file_length += 1;
    }

    return file_length;
}

void merge(int arr[], int left, int middle, int right) //function to sort unsorted array
{  
    int i, j, k;
    //create array partition
    int left_partition = middle - left + 1;
    int right_partition = right - middle;

    int first[left_partition], second[right_partition]; //set up temporary arrays

    //move left side of array to temp array
    for (i = 0; i < left_partition; i++)
    {
        first[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    //move right side of array to temp array
    for (j = 0; j < right_partition; j++)
    {
        second[j] = arr[middle + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = left;

    while (i < left_partition && j < right_partition)
    {
        //sort the array into one array
        if (first[i] <= second[j])
        {
            arr[k] = first[i];
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = second[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < left_partition)
    {
        arr[k] = first[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < right_partition)
    {
        arr[k] = second[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) //splits array in half, calls self on both halves, then merges the halves
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int middle = (left + (right-1))/ 2;
        merge_sort(arr, left, middle); //split left half
        merge_sort(arr, middle+1, right); //split right half
        merge(arr, left, middle, right); //merge both halves
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*WILL CREATES THREAD ID 1, 2, 3 */
    pthread_t thread_id1; // creates first thread id
    pthread_attr_t attr_1; // creates thread attributes
    pthread_t thread_id2; // creates second thread id
    pthread_attr_t attr_2; // second thread attributes
    pthread_t thread_id3; // creates third thread id
    pthread_attr_t attr_3;// third thread attributes

    /* WILL READ IN FILE WITH UNSORTED ARRAY*/
    char *file_name = argv[1];
    flength = read_length(file_name);
    array_whole = read_file(file_name);

  clock_t t;

    int m;
    printf("UNSORTED: ");
    for (m = 0; m < alength; m++) {
        if (m == alength - 1) {
            printf("%d \n", array_whole[m]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", array_whole[m]);
        }
    }

  t=clock();
    /*WILL CREATE THREAD 1,2,3 */
    char *thread_1 = "first"; // creates first thread
    pthread_attr_init(&attr_1); //finds attributes
    pthread_create(&thread_id1, &attr_1, run, thread_1); // create 1st thread
    char *thread_2 = "second";
    pthread_attr_init(&attr_2);
    pthread_create(&thread_id2, &attr_2, run, thread_2);  // create 2nd thread
    char *thread_3 = "third";
    pthread_attr_init(&attr_3);
    pthread_create(&thread_id3, &attr_2, run, thread_3);  // create 3rd thread

    /*WILL JOIN ALL THE THREADS TOGETHER*/
    pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL); 
    pthread_join(thread_id2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id3, NULL);

  t=clock() - t;
  double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    /* WILL PRINT ALL SORTED VALUES */
    int i;
    printf("SORTED: ");
    for (i = 0; i < alength; i++) {
        if (i == alength - 1) {
            printf("%d \n", array_whole[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", array_whole[i]);
        }
    }
  printf("elapsed time = %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);

    pthread_exit(0);

    return 0;
}


void *run(void *parameters)
{
    int centerspot = alength / 2;
    if (strcmp(parameters, "first") == 0) {
        merge_sort(array_whole, 0, centerspot);
    }

    if (strcmp(parameters, "second") == 0) {
        merge_sort(array_whole, centerspot + 1, alength - 1);
    }

    if (strcmp(parameters, "third") == 0) {
        merge_sort(array_whole, 0, alength - 1);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Single thread code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void *run(void *parameters); /* threads call this function */
int alength, flength;
int *array_whole;

FILE *input_file;
int *read_file(char *file_name) {
    input_file = fopen("soulfoodinput.txt", "rt"); // open file
    int arraysize = flength;
    char line[80];
    int integer;
    int index = 0;
    int *input = malloc(arraysize * sizeof(int));


    while (fgets(line, 80, input_file) != NULL) 
{
        sscanf(line, "%d", &integer); // read the integer value
        input[index] = integer;
        //printf(line);
        ++index;
        ++alength;
    }
    fclose(input_file); // close the file    
    return input;
}


int read_length(char *file_name) {
    input_file = fopen(file_name, "rt"); // open file
    char line[80];
    int file_length = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 80, input_file) != NULL) {
        file_length += 1;
    }

    return file_length;
}

void merge(int arr[], int left, int middle, int right) //function to sort unsorted array
{  
    int i, j, k;
    //create array partition
    int left_partition = middle - left + 1;
    int right_partition = right - middle;

    int first[left_partition], second[right_partition]; //set up temporary arrays

    //move left side of array to temp array
    for (i = 0; i < left_partition; i++)
    {
        first[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    //move right side of array to temp array
    for (j = 0; j < right_partition; j++)
    {
        second[j] = arr[middle + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = left;

    while (i < left_partition && j < right_partition)
    {
        //sort the array into one array
        if (first[i] <= second[j])
        {
            arr[k] = first[i];
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = second[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < left_partition)
    {
        arr[k] = first[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < right_partition)
    {
        arr[k] = second[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) //splits array in half, calls self on both halves, then merges the halves
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int middle = (left + (right-1))/ 2;
        merge_sort(arr, left, middle); //split left half
        merge_sort(arr, middle+1, right); //split right half
        merge(arr, left, middle, right); //merge both halves
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*WILL CREATES THREAD ID */
    pthread_t thread_id1; // creates first thread id
    pthread_attr_t attr_1; // creates thread attributes

    /* WILL READ IN FILE WITH UNSORTED ARRAY*/
    char *file_name = argv[1];
    flength = read_length(file_name);
    array_whole = read_file(file_name);

  clock_t t;

    int m;
    printf("UNSORTED: ");
    for (m = 0; m < alength; m++) {
        if (m == alength - 1) {
            printf("%d \n", array_whole[m]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", array_whole[m]);
        }
    }

  t=clock();
    /*WILL CREATE THREAD 1,2,3 */
    char *thread_1 = "first"; // creates first thread
    pthread_attr_init(&attr_1); //finds attributes
    pthread_create(&thread_id1, &attr_1, run, thread_1); // create 1st thread

    /*WILL JOIN ALL THE THREADS TOGETHER*/
    pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL); 


  t=clock() - t;
  double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    /* WILL PRINT ALL SORTED VALUES */
    int i;
    printf("SORTED: ");
    for (i = 0; i < alength; i++) {
        if (i == alength - 1) {
            printf("%d \n", array_whole[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", array_whole[i]);
        }
    }
  printf("elapsed time = %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);

    pthread_exit(0);

    return 0;
}


void *run(void *parameters)
{
    int centerspot = alength / 2;

        merge_sort(array_whole, 0, centerspot);

        merge_sort(array_whole, centerspot + 1, alength - 1);

        merge_sort(array_whole, 0, alength - 1);


    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly (this unreadable) and try to reduce it to a minimal example.

Comment: To be clear, you have one thread sorting the fist half, another sorting the second half.  While that is going on, what is the third thread doing?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here at all. Should not the last merge not wait until the two halves are sorted?

Comment: @MartinJames the third thread combines the two threads together. The first thread partitions the left side of the array and sorts it and the second thread partitions the right side of the array and sorts it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi threading's performance can be measured with large volume of data. With very small volume of data you cannot measure the performance of multithreaded application. The reasons:-

> 1.To create a thread O/S need to allocation of memory to each thread which take time (even though it is tiny bit.)
>
> 2.When you create multi threads it needs context switching which also take time.
>
> 3.Need to release memory allocated to threads which also take time.
>
> 4.It depends on number of processor and total memory (RAM) in your machine

So when you try with small operation with multi threads it's performance will be as same as single thread or even less. So your outcome is perfect in this case. To Measure the performance of multithread architecture use large amount of data with complex operation then only you can see the differences.

Comment: even after using a larger dataset in this case an array of 1000 integers im getting a faster single thread computing time compared to multi thread

Comment: That is not large. If you consider your system hardware that is very tiny actually.

Answer (score 1):

Threads take time to set up and launch. The larger the amount of work to be done, the more chance that multiple threads will reduce the overall time taken to complete the task.

In your example, I'm guessing that file *soulfoodinput.txt* is not very large, so I would suggest making it larger, if possible it should contain hundreds or even thousands of lines. Then see if the multi-thread code runs quicker than the single-thread.